# How to generate/replicate similar nodes in DOM efficiently

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an `Expense` resource which can have a `Category` assigned. In front end each category is represented by a `<label>` element, clicking on one category goes to API, fetches the subcategories and then displays them to the user using the same `<label>` as used with the category we clicked - I use `cloneNode` and then manipulate it (change classes, values etc). This process just looks inelegant - is there a better way to do it?

```
  cloneLabel(label_node, subcategory) {
    let category_label_copy = label_node.cloneNode(true)
    let radio_input = category_label_copy.firstElementChild.cloneNode()
    category_label_copy.className = "btn btn-outline-primary"
    radio_input.setAttribute('value', subcategory['id'])
    category_label_copy.textContent = subcategory['name']
    category_label_copy.appendChild(radio_input)
    return category_label_copy
  }
```

Comment: Cant't help without any code. The proccess sounds good for me.

Comment: I added the function which I use to clone and manipulate the node I later inject into the the list of subcategories. This is more of a general question though - is this normal that I take a node from DOM and manipulate it using 10+ lines or it's more common to have some kind of templates (in this case a template/generic label) ready in the backend to render/fill with data by calling an API